# Is there any method to protect developer from lethal frequencies?

Tags: safety

My physiological [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/66552/2387) to *"[Why do 0.02A fuses not protect a person? Why no protection from shocks?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66538/why-do-0-02a-fuses-not-protect-a-person-why-no-protection-from-shocks)"* is raising new questions. So is there any method to protect developer from lethal frequencies?

Comment: I've done a bunch of electrical safety lectures from the biomedical point of view, and have never heard of lethal frequencies.  Yes, there are periods in the cardiac cycle that are more susceptible to problems from electric shock, but this has little to do w/ frequency.  There is a pain/frequency graph that shows 50-60 Hz is the most painful, most damaging frequency, but it's not magically super-lethal.

Comment: What is your question; is it anything to do with lethal frequencies being in the frequency range of 2.45GHz? Why is this question linked with a question about 20mA fuses? Why then do also draw-in "shocks". This question is not a real question and I vote to close it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman well it is odd. This point was raised in a nationawide medical examination audited by many medical professionals: AC of specific frequency -- not being super high voltage and not being super high current -- can kill (do physical damage) if it able to go well against the HR (move in a way that is not normal to hearth). Then again a very high frequency that just stops hearth may be much less lethal. I am very skeptical whether there is any way to protect for this because it depends on so many factors, anyway moved here because asked.

Comment: @Andyaka stop trolling like [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/66418/2387), particularly if you don't understand the topic. It is fine if appropriate arguments but you haven't clearly read my writing in the other question or understood the physiological aspect here.

Comment: Happy to look into it if you can provide a citation.

Comment: @ScottSeidman will do my best, takes some time -- thank you for your interest, I think this is very fascinating thing! Trying to find authoritative physiological book...

Comment: From shock, nothing but knowledge can protect you from ignorance. From High Frequence, it tends to pass over a body, because the impedance is lower. (see Tesla Coil)

Answer (score 1):

A specific way to do this would be to capacitively couple the circuit, so that only high frequencies could pass. As far as I understand it, the concern is about accidentally building an "anti-defibrilator" which interferes with heart operation?

Comment: A defibrillator MAXIMALLY interferes with normal heart rhythms by attempting to contract the whole heart at one time.  The physiology is a bit complex.  After a muscle fiber contracts, it is unable to contract again for a little while.  In a normal heart, the way the heartbeat passes through the heart, it should stop at heart fibers that have already contracted.  If the wave slows or goes in a curvy path, this doesn't work, the hearbeat passes on in an efficient pattern, no longer generating pumping, but quivering.  Defib makes the heart unable to contract for a while, hopefully fixing things.