# Choosing the right PTC Resettable Fuse for a protection circuit

Tags: power, protection

## Power shield protection circuit specs

Hello! Iv'e been creating an ESP32 power shield and started designing the protection circuit for the power supply with the following features:

1. Reverse polarity protection.
2. Overvoltage protection.
3. Overcurrent protection.

However, it is important to note that the design I'm using is based on [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48831/help-designing-an-inverse-polarity-and-overload-crowbar-protection-circuit)

### Input

Supplied through either a 9V 2.5A power source to a screw terminal or a 9V 2.5A power charger to a barrel jack.

### Output

The output of the protection circuit will be connected to 3 different regulators:

1. Vin (Connected to internal ESP32 regulator that takes 3.3v 500ma at load).
2. 3.3V 1A regulator.
3. 5V 1A regulator.

### Component links

I Chose the following components for the circuit:

1. [D3 (Schottky Barrier Diode)](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_MDD-Microdiode-Electronics-1N5822_C2476.html)
2. [F2 (PTC Resettable Fuse)](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/PTC-Fuse_1-6A-Self-recovery_C135411.html)
3. [D4 (Zener Diode)](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Zener-Diodes_ON-Semiconductor-ON-Semiconductor-1N5346BRLG_C9077.html)

The PTC Resettable Fuse was chosen after reading [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141311/did-i-choose-the-correct-fuse-for-my-usb-powered-circuit)

### Schematic

[image]

## The Questions

1. Do I need to put a series resistor with D4 or is the PTC Resettable Fuse sufficient ?
2. Did i choose the correct PTC Resettable Fuse ?

## P.S.

I'm new to electronics so please go easy on me if I miss obvious stuff.

Comment: You do not need D3 . In case of reverse polarity D4 will shorten circuit and fuse should trip.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach would work, at the expense of efficiency due to the diode drop on the input.

Here's a discussion on the topic: https://www.edn.com/protecting-against-reverse-polarity-methods-examined-part-1/

This device from Maxim provides overvoltage and reverse protection, with the addition of two FETs. It has no diode drop, so less power loss. More here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/protection-control/protection-ics/MAX4864L.html

Add a PTC of your choice in series and you would have a complete solution.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the useful information source. I will definitely consider some of the designs there. However, regarding the protection ic - The efficiency is not the factor i'm looking to solve as to keep the circuit simple. In addition, you pointed out that I can add a ptc of my choice but my question is: did I choose the right ptc for the circuit above ? (I linked to the actual components i intend to use)

Comment: The difference in PTCs will be in how fast they activate. And with that, comes a tradeoff in voltage drop (efficiency again): the faster it acts, the more resistance it has to have. I think something rated in the 1.5 ~ 3A range can work.

Comment: The PTC I chose has an ih of 1.6A and It of 3.2A. however will the resistance it provides be sufficient from blowing the D4 diode which can tolerate only 5w ? I still cant figure out if the PTC I chose is correct and if I should add a series resistor to D4 or not.

Comment: Don't add the series resistance - you want as much of the IR drop to be in the PTC as possible so that it will trigger quickly. You can use 2 diodes in parallel to be safe.